# Object #<Resource> has no method 'save'

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I have a fairly simple AngularJS app that is consuming a Spring MVC Rest API.

I am able to query the API. But I am having trouble Creating objects. I get the following error and have not been able to figure out why. I have looked at similar questions but my API is returning the created object and from what I can tell my injections are correct.

Here is the stack from the javascript console:

```
TypeError: Object #<Resource> has no method 'save'
at Object.TeamListCtrl.$scope.addPlayer(http://localhost:8000/app/js/controllers.js:17:13)
at elementFns (http://localhost:8000/app/lib/angular/angular.js:6365:19)
at Object.$get.Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8000/app/lib/angular/angular.js:8057:28)
at Object.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8000/app/lib/angular/angular.js:8137:23)
at Object.ng.config.$provide.decorator.$delegate.__proto__.$apply (http://localhost:8000/app/index.html:855:30)
at HTMLFormElement.ngIncludeDirective.restrict (http://localhost:8000/app/lib/angular/angular.js:13159:11)
at event.preventDefault (http://localhost:8000/app/lib/angular/angular.js:1992:10)
at Array.forEach (native)
at forEach (http://localhost:8000/app/lib/angular/angular.js:130:11)
at HTMLFormElement.eventHandler (http://localhost:8000/app/lib/angular/angular.js:1991:5)
```

Here is my controller:

```
function TeamListCtrl($scope, Shared, Teams, Players) {
$scope.teams = Teams.query();

$scope.addPlayer = function() {

    var newPlayer = new Players({
        position: $scope.newPlayer.position,
        lastName: $scope.newPlayer.lastName,
        firstName: $scope.newPlayer.firstName
    });

    newPlayer.save({teamId: $scope.newPlayer.teamId});
};
}

TeamListCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'Shared', 'Teams', 'Players'];
```

Here is my service:

```
var teamsService = angular.module('teamsService', ['ngResource']);

teamsService.factory('Players', function($resource){
    return $resource('http://localhost\\:8080/api/teams/players/:teamId', {teamId:'@teamId'}, {
        save: {method:'POST'}
    });
});
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to post the resource, like this

```
var newPlayer = {
        teamId: $scope.newPlayer.teamId,
        position: $scope.newPlayer.position,
        lastName: $scope.newPlayer.lastName,
        firstName: $scope.newPlayer.firstName
    };

Players.save(newPlayer);
```

Comment: That worked. I had to change the api to include teamId in the player object and update the link but it worked. Thanks for the help. 

Where may I ask did you find that info? From the angularJs docs it always showed creating an instance and then calling save from the instance instead of statically as you recommended.

Comment: Yes AngularJS docs show examples as you have shown. It should work for you too. You can try to call the $save method that is available on each entity returned when you do get using resource. How you are doing new `Players`, i think is not the right way. If you see all examples they do a get, followed by update on the entity returned. The docs do not make it very clear, but the return parameter explanation give what methods are available on resource and for the entities returned by resource.